# How do snap packages affect root partition size in 16.04?

Tags: partitioning, 16.04

I've read that snap packages are bigger because they contain all of their library dependencies.  I normally make separate `/` and `/home` partitions.

For a fresh install of 16.04, should I make `/` bigger than the 30GB I normally reserve for `/` in 14.04 to account for larger packages?

Disk space is a consideration on a SSD.

Comment: Well, how big are the Snappy packages that you want to install? The answer totally depends on that.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I think the question is what happens when you install *multiple* e.g., 10 snap  packages that have the same dependency—do you need x10 more space compared to `.deb` packages (where the dependency is installed exactly once).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: This is probably the underlying question but what OP is asking here is “Is 30 GB more than previously the right size?” which depends on a lot of factors that we don't know and also on a lot of personal opinion.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes, the actual partition size is less important than the general question: what is the typical bloat factor going to be for snap packages?  From there, one could extrapolate their partition size based on past experience.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have media files on `/`, 30GB will probably be enough space for a while.

We are still exploring how snaps are going to be used, so it's hard to give you numbers on this, but I wouldn't expect to need that much space unless you were wanting to install all the steam catalogue, as snaps, on a single system.

Comment: The tendency is apps now cam in snap/appimage/flatpack, nothing we can do. I'm on a similar situation, a 30GB / partition 80% used on a 2016 SSD. I'm not sure if I should worry about its lifespan but I regret a little bit not giving some more space. Yes I could boot with a liveCD and resize...